# How to for loop an array then put elements into a list format?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program which `scanf` integers and `printf` in double.

Here is my code:

```
int main(void) {
int arraySize;
scanf("%d",&arraySize);
double vector[arraySize];
for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++) scanf("%lf", &vector[i]);
for(int a=0;a<arraySize;a++) printf("VECTORS:[%lf]",vector[a]);
}
```

Since I need to `for loop` every element in the array then `printf` all of them one by one.
this is the output I had:

```
VECTORS:[1.000000] VECTORS:[2.000000] VECTORS:[3.000000]
```

How can I change the format of the `printf` function and get ouput like this:

```
VECTOR: [ 1.000, 2.000, 3.000 ]
```

Comment: Hint: Print `VECTOR: [` once, then the contents separated by commas, then the closing brace. Skip the comma after the last entry by checking your index vs. the array size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your one major mistake is your array size.  I know your compiler won't issue any warning but this is not any feature which language provide so size must be a 
constant numerical value or const expression.

So in short you can't create array After asking size from user. This is completely wrong.

```
int arraySize;
scanf("%d",&arraySize);
double vector[arraySize];
```

You must make size const. If you want less values than the declared size you can decrease the no of times for loop will run but you can't decide array size as inputted by user.

```
const int size = 10; //  this is how your size should be. Even your compiler allowed VLA you should not try this. size of arrays must be constant.


int main()
{
  unsigned int i,s;
   int arr[size];
   printf ("Enter the size of array.");
   scanf("%d",&s);
   for(i = 0 ; i<s;i++){
     scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
   }
   for(i = 0 ; i<s;i++){
     arr[i] = arr[i]*arr[i];
   }
   for(i = 0 ; i<s;i++){
     printf("%d",arr[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Print `VECTOR` once then loop over all the vectors and output them in the desired format.

```
const int size = 10;
int main(void) {
   double vector[size];

   for(int i=0;i<size;i++) 
      scanf("%lf", &vector[i]);

   printf("VECTOR: [ ");

   for(int a=0;a<size;a++){
      printf("%lf", vector[a]);
      if(i < size - 1)
         printf(", ");
   }

   printf(" ]");
}
```

Comment: C don't support VLA . Modify your code to make it const literal.

Comment: should u define i in the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory dynamically to use it.
Use the printf in the code below to define precision.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int arraySize = 0;

    scanf("%d",&arraySize);

    double *vector = (double *) calloc(arraySize, sizeof(double));

    for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++) {
       scanf("%lf", &vector[i]);
    }

    printf("VECTORS:[");
    int a;
    for(a=0;a<arraySize;a++) {
        printf(" %.3lf",vector[a]);
        if (a<(arraySize-1)) {
            printf(",");
        } else {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("]");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your for loop to take 3 elements at once.

```
for(a=0;a<arraySize;a+=3) {
   printf("VECTORS:[%lf", vector[a]);
   if (a+1 < arraySize) printf(", %lf", vector[a+1]);
   if (a+2 < arraySize) printf(", %lf", vector[a+2]);
   printf("]\n");
}
```

Comment: what if the user enter the array size as 5?

Comment: It will be something like this `VECTORS:[1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000] VECTORS:[4.000000, 5.000000, 0.000000]`. What is the expected output?